# Como chamar o mês anterior no R?

Tags: r, data

Preciso que o R me diga mês anterior ao que estamos, isto é, estamos em "2018-05" e preciso que ele me dê "2018-04".
 Até o momento a minha solução foi:

```
format(Sys.Date()-as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%d")),"%Y-%m")
```

Acredito que deva haver uma solução mais "limpa".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode utilizar o `mondate`:

```
library(mondate)

mondate(Sys.Date())-1
# mondate: timeunits="months"
# [1] 05/12/2018
```

E para formatar somente ano e mês:

```
format(mondate(Sys.Date())-1, "%Y-%m")
# [1] "2018-05"
```

Answer (score 3):

Com `lubridate`, pode fazer assim:

```
library(lubridate)
month(today() - months(1))
```